# Net Core 2.2 with Letsencrypt on CentOS 7

Tags: .net-core, centos7

I am trying to use letsencrypt certificate in my asp.net core 2.2
letsencrypt certificate already installed and works properly..(SSL Labs tested)

== thrown exception ==

```
[FTL] Unable to start Kestrel. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib at 
Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle) at 
Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) at 
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) at 
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load() at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.ValidateOptions() at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

my appsettings.json

```
...
,
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "/etc/myletsencrypt/cert.pfx"  // ==> this is converted from .pem to pfx
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

== program.cs==

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
    
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()   
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000","https://0.0.0.0:5001");
```

== startup.cs ==

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

        // linux setting
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{api}/{controller}/{action}");
        });
}
```

What did I miss?
Anybody has experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed this, by setting up reverse proxy into apache:

I only use port 5000 and set proxypass for /api/
so if users access https://dev.myexample.com/api/xxxx then it goes to http://localhost:5000/api/xxxx
I thought it's good, rather than I have to do NAT port 5000

please let me know if there is a better thought

thanks & regards
Don

=== httpd.conf ===

```
<VirtualHost dev.example.com:443>
  ServerName dev.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev.example.com
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/dev.example.com.error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/dev.example.com.access.log combined

  SSLEngine On

 <Directory "/var/www/html/dev.example.com">
    allow from all
    Options None
  </Directory>

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt//dev.example.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/dev.example.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/dev.example.com/chain.pem

<Location /api/>
ProxyPass http://localhost:5000/api/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

== program.cs ==

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

==
== startup.cs ==

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseHsts();

                // linux setting
                app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
                {
                    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
                });
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{api}/{controller}/{action}");
            });


        }
```